# Study on Padya/Prathipad

Tags: vedas

What does the scriptures say about Veda study on Pratipad (first thithi after Full moon or new moon; Padyami)? I heard we should not study.
Are there any mentions of this restriction and reasons for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some occasions and situations when Veda study is forbidden. Among them, as far as the forbidden Tithis are concerned, Purnima (full moon), Amavashya (new moon), 2 Chaturdashis and 2 Ashtamis of any month are mentioned as the ones in Manu.

> 4.113. Nor during a fog, nor while the sound of arrows is audible, nor during both the twilights, nor on the newmoon day, nor on the
> fourteenth and the eighth (days of each half-month), nor on the
> full-moon day.
>
> 4.114. The new-moon day destroys the teacher, the fourteenth (day) the pupil, the eighth and the full-moon days (destroy all remembrance of)
> the Veda; let him therefore avoid (reading on) those (days).
>
> 4.115. A Brahmana shall not recite (the Veda) during a dust-storm, nor while the sky is preternaturally red, nor while jackals howl, nor
> while the barking of dogs, the braying of donkeys, or the grunting of
> camels (is heard), nor while (he is seated) in a company

Prohibition regarding the Pratipad Tithi is not mentioned here.